# Can TIE Fighters jump to lightspeed?

Tags: star-wars

We see in *Return of the Jedi* that the Rebel fleet, including the fighters (B-Wing, X-Wing, etc.) make the jump to lightspeed to get to Endor and commence their assault on the Death Star.

Are TIE fighters also capable of travelling faster than light? Or do they need to rely on being docked in a Star Destroyer or the Death Star in order to get far distances?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**, not the TIE/LN fighter (commonly known as the "TIE fighter") or [TIE/IN Interceptor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE/IN_interceptor) ("TIE Interceptor").

In Episode IV, the *Millenium Falcon* comes out of hyperspace and encounters a TIE fighter from the Death Star. [Obi-Wan says](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) it's a "short range fighter" and "a fighter that size couldn't get this deep into space on its own":

> Luke: It followed us!
>
> Ben: No. It's a short range fighter.
>
> Han: There aren't any bases around here. Where did it come from?
>
> ...
>
> Ben: A fighter that size couldn't get this deep into space on its own.

The (Legends) Wookieepedia article for the [TIE fighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE/LN_starfighter) also explicitly says it lacks a hyperdrive.

However, certain advanced or upgraded models -- such as the [TIE Advanced x1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE_Advanced_x1) used by Darth Vader at the Battle of Yavin -- did include a hyperdrive.

Answer (score 4):

The TIE Fighter [lacks a hyperdrive](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE/LN_starfighter) according to Wookieepedia.  That also jives with Obi-Wan's comment that it's a "short range fighter" in episode IV.

In the X-Wing video game, the X-Wing is a much more capable fighter than the TIE, including the hyperdrive and the addition of shields, which the TIE also lacked.  The TIE's strength was in speed and maneuverability.

Comment: They're also often supported by the ships launching them, and in their numbers.